# The expanding <div> conundrum

Tags: html, css

I am just learning HTML and CSS (JavaScript will be next.)  I am developing a website on which I have two boxes (defined as `<div>`s) side by side.  They have different horizontal sizes, but each has "height: 1000px".
The large one sits right of the narrow one, and is defined by

```
<section style = "width:900px; height: 1000px; margin 10px; padding: 20px; background: #BBD1FF; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
```

I added text within the confines of both boxes, and everything was fine.  Then I added more text in the rightmost box, and the box seems to have expanded it's vertical dimension.  The original and the new text in the box don't come close to filling the box, so what is going on here?  I can't find any property of `<div>` which seems to relate to this.

Comment: put some css and html code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Your code would be really useful here.  Consider using something like jsfiddle.net if you don't want to link to/post your full code

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i've taken a guess to what I think your trying to do. Basically, add max-width to your divs to prevent them from expanding. Here's a JSFiddle with something simple what I think your looking to do.

```
.div-one--left {
    height: 1000px;
    max-width: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Also, when dealing with widths. Its good practise to always use percentages. You can't build responsively if your using pixels as widths (but thats off topic slightly).

http://jsfiddle.net/63617aLj/